CUDA & OpenCL GPU Kernel function queuing are far too slow. Any faster method or technology? Future perhaps? Is this a known issue?
Background
I have spent the past week doing experiments towards using GPU for audio processing/synthesis, for example in areas like finite difference modeling (eg. wave equation) where the equations are highly parallelized at least at each serial time step.
However, there has appeared a massive bottleneck which I am not sure is solvable.
Queuing of the kernel GPU functions is far too slow. I have tried an OpenCL method and just now a CUDA method and they both are extremely slow. To a crushing extent.
Requirements
For real time audio processing or synthesis, audio is typically at 44100 samples per second (Hz) and the audio buffer is typically at most 512 or 1024 samples.
This means we have 23 ms (at 1024 buffer) to process each buffer. In real world scenarios, you only have a tiny fraction of this, as there are often multiple audio processes that must finish in this time on the same CPU thread.
Problem
In order to do any useful audio work, one must finish processing one sample before moving on to the next. Furthermore, you may need several steps to go through per sample. Even if each step is highly parallel in itself, it would be hard to do anything useful without 3-4 steps per sample.
Both in CUDA and OpenCL I have found, in pseudo-code, running:
for (int i=0; i < 1024; i++){
    enqueueStep1();
    enqueueStep2();
    enqueueStep3();
    enqueueStep4();
}
runQueueOrWaitTilDone();

Takes around 10-12 ms. This has been using empty or near empty functions, so this is just the extra burden and cost of queueing the functions, not from heavy processing.
Method

OpenCL - I used this [OpenCL wrapper][1] which allows you to easily create a Kernel kernel and then kernel.enqueue_run(); as many times as you wish then, kernel.finish_queue(); to run it.

CUDA - I used the default CUDA project created by Visual Studio 2022 that has a simple add function built into it. I created a stream so could be sure it was all running on one process and nothing else was interfering. Then I wrapped the basic add function they give you in a for loop and ran cudaStreamSynchronize(stream) after this loop.


Running four operations in a loop of 1024: OpenCL with completely empty functions took around 8-12 ms (less if no arguments were passed in, more if they were) and CUDA around 12 ms with the basic add function (basically also empty function).
Result
This makes real time audio processing or wave equation work essentially useless on GPU's at the present.
Although in theory a GPU would be great for solving something like each step of a finite difference wave equation, the cost of simply enqueuing the many serial steps required is too great. You are eating up ~half your total audio buffer time just with enqueuing the empty functions.
Question
If you have a hypoethetical function like this where you were trying to process all 1024 samples in one buffer (OpenCL Wrapper code):
kernel void processAudioBlock(global float* A, global float* B, global float* C) { 

    const uint n = get_global_id(0);
    const uint N = get_global_size(0);

    //iterate through 1024 times for 1024 samples in audio buffer
    for (int i=0; i< 1024;i++){

        //Step 1: perform function that does not depend on neighbors
        C[n] = A[n]+B[n];

        //Step 2: perform function that DOES depend on neighbors (and thus needs Step 1 complete for all other samples)
        if (n > 0 && n < N - 1) {
            C[n] = (C[n] + C[n] + C[n - 1] + C[n + 1]) * 0.25f;
        }
    }
}

As you can see, step 1 must be completed for all samples before it moves on to step 2, as step 2 requires looking at the calculations done by the neighboring GPU cores. And hypothetically (in a real case) before you move on to the next sample, the prior sample must be fully done (step 2 must be done for all cores before looping to the next step 1).
I believe I have misunderstood how GPU's work. I thought I needed multiple kernel calls to keep the cores synchronized in such a case.
However, is it the case that when you run step 1 or 2 for example here, ALL cores do so at exactly the same time? And ALL cores are done step 1 before step 2 is run?
Thanks for any clarification.
[1]: https://github.com/ProjectPhysX/OpenCL-Wrapper

one must finish processing one sample before moving on to the next: This sounds like a no-go for GPU processing. You need at least several thousand threads in parallel for a GPU to be useful. you may need several steps to go through per sample: So why are your steps not part of the same kernel? Why is the same kernel not looping over all samples in the buffer to avoid the launch overhead? You may also be interested in persistent kernels

Seems odd to launch a separate kernel for each sample? How does that achieve the required parallelism for gpu processing? Launching a single kernel for your whole buffer is likely what you need to do instead. GPUs aren't fast, they can just do lots of things at once, if you have a serial problem then even a fairly weak CPU will be faster than the best GPU

"Queuing of the kernel GPU functions is far too slow" This is expected: queuing a GPU kernel requires to extract kernel parameters, perform an expensive system call communicating with the GPU driver, sending data to the PCI interface, queue the kernel in the scheduling queue of the GPU (and possibly awake the GPU if needed), then scheduled later. A system call typically require 1-10 µs. This can be even higher due to security patch on x86-64 CPU the last years.

"Takes around 10-12 ms" For submitting 4096 kernels and running them, this is pretty fast. This means 2.4-2.9 µs/kernel which is actually rather pretty good. It can be significantly higher on other platforms (possibly with other GPU vendors), like 10-20 µs/kernel. Streams will not speed this up significantly since you have a long chain of kernel to execute. They are good when you need to execute kernels concurrently. Your code is similar to running 4096 parallel fork-join loop at ~1 µs/loop on CPUs (generally running at a ~2x higher frequency): it is not reasonable due to scheduling.

GPU kernel graphs can help, but ultimately scheduling will be the issue on GPUs (running at a relatively-low frequency with a high-latency memory). At Homer512 pointed out, the key is to do that in the same unique kernel (or at least merge some kernel like the 4 steps in only 1). In CUDA, you can perform global synchronizations in a kernel thanks to cooperative groups (IDK for OpenCL), but this may require non-trivial changes in your kernel so to work (and be possibly sub-optimal regarding the exact computation done -- still much better than flooding the GPU with a lot of kernels).

Regarding your computation, I would personally try to write a fast CPU implementation using SIMD units and possibly multiple cores (while taking care of NUMA effects, frequency scaling, reusing threads between iteration, and pinning threads to core). 1024 samples is not a lot and recent CPU can compute basic operations on 16 x stereo 16-bit sound samples per cycle per core (at >= 4 GHz). At this scale, inter-core communication might even be too expensive due to the latency of atomics and more specifically the L3 cache latency.

Last but not least, note that for audio computations, DSP and FPGA are AFAIK generally preferred (pretty specialized for that). They can do operations at a lower-latency than GPUs, and can be more efficient for specialized operation 16-bit integers (possibly 16-bit floats too regarding the actual operation performed). Global synchronization might be an issue on them too, but certainly not as much as on CPU/GPUs.

Thank you so much @JérômeRichard for your detailed reply. I believe I have misunderstood how GPU processing works. I was under the impression that each GPU core works on its own thread essentially (each core receives the kernel instruction and completes it on its own desynchronized from its neighbors). That is why I thought you needed separate kernels to keep each step synchronized. I believe that is wrong though. I presume each GPU core runs in synchrony when doing one kernel. I updated my question to clarify my confusion. Can you reply once more just to put it to rest? Thanks again. :)

yes GPUs are basically SIMD devices, they can only do a single operation at a time, but they can perform that operation over a lot of data at once

@JérômeRichard is correct, GPUs and real-time audio are not great bedfellows. For FDTD work you will want to look at writing the stencil as SIMD. The bottlenecks of everything like OpenCL, CUDA, Metal shaders &c. Are going to be too high for real-time audio. By the time you mitigate the bottleneck by increasing buffer size, your latency will be too long. The solution for performance is to use FPGA hardware, or write for a specific DSP chip, but that is a hardware solution, not strictly software. You could look at a modal synthesis approach, but that has its own limitations

Great thanks @AlanBirtles. If each step of the command finishes before the next for all cores of the GPU (like SIMD) then I can write the full audio block in one kernel and this solves it. I will just delete the question then unless one of you wants some points for writing an answer formally. Whatever works. Thanks.

In your new code, you need to add synchronizations. Threads are not (automatically/implicitly) synchronized (well, actually, threads are grouped in chunk called "warp" which are generally synchronized). Otherwise, there will be a race condition which can cause data corruption. In CUDA, there is __syncthreads() to synchronize all threads of a block (so not the whole kernel). In your case, I think you need a global synchronization. To do so, I think you need to use cooperative groups.

Regarding how GPUs work, the best thing to do is to read the related part of the CUDA programming guide explaining that (eg. the first parts). Many things are not specific to Nvidia GPUs (AMD GPUs are rather similar overall) so a lot of thing also applies in OpenCL (though the terms are different : e.g. sub-group vs warp, work-group vs block, work-item vs thread, etc.). I do not think global synchronizations are possible in OpenCL yet as it is in CUDA with cooperative groups (AFAIK this is pretty new in CUDA).

Note there are significantly faster ways to do stencils like this (both on GPUs and CPUs) though this is complicated. There are many research paper on this topic. A typical optimization is to operate on tiles so to reduce the memory pressure and strongly reduce synchronizations/communications (possibly with a complicated shape). I advise you to use tools doing that for you instead of rewriting the wheel if you can (the only one I know that might fit your needs is Halide).

@AlanBirtles This is not really correct. A better-suited model for GPUs is the SIMT model. Indeed, all threads are not fully synchronized like in SIMD. On a pure SIMD device, the OP code would be correct, but not in SIMT. For example, threads of a block are not synchronized unless you manually request it, while threads of a warp are (except in some complicated cases on new Nvidia GPUs starting from Volta).

@JérômeRichard, can you then clarify if my code in the OP is in fact valid or not? Ie. is step 1 certainly completed for all data before step 2 is run for each GPU core? Or if not, is there some way to "synchronize" between step 1 and 2 without making them separate kernel requests (because this adds up too many requests and latency as noted).

According to this reference, with NVIDIA: "Syncing threads is also not a simple matter. You can only sync threads within a single Streaming Multiprocessor (SM). Everything outside the SM is unsyncable from inside the kernel. You'll have to write seperate kernels and launch them one after the other." https://riptutorial.com/opencl/example/31156/threads--and-execution Which means if I go NVIDIA only (CUDA) and keep my thread count to 32 I can attain synchrony. But above that I would need separate kernel requests sequentially. Correct?

It is not correct as mentioned in the previous comments : "you need to add synchronizations". The next comments also explain how to do that (in CUDA). Did you read the links? If you want to do that in OpenCL then I do not think there is a simple way (tiling is mandatory to avoid running too many kernels like you did).

The link you provide is old and obsolete (like a lot of things on RIP, hence the name)... It was true long ago but not any-more. The link of Nvidia is newer and reliable (written by from Nvidia developers themselves)! Please read it carefully! Note this is for CUDA and not OpenCL (this is certainly not possible in OpenCL yet).

I understand the operation you've shown is just a placeholder. If in the the real one the relation of an index to its predecessor is associative, like a sum, product or maximum, you can use the algorithms designed for prefix sums, such as thrust's implementation

The solution was to use barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) in OpenCL liberally inside my kernel to separate each step. Then when running, it one must make sure OpenCL workgroups are coordinated so that each workgroup is expected to stay in sync only with itself.
Ie. barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE) can only work across one workgroup at a time. But each workgroup can be up to 1024 in size or more based on the complexity of the Kernel and GPU capacity. All of which can be calculated using the OpenCL API.
And when you run the OpenCL Kernel, you can request number of workgroups and total thread count so it is all predictable.


This text answer does not answer your literal question. Consider a bit of rephrasing. 2. If this resolved your problem, you should accept the answer (yes, your own answer).


The part
if (n > 0 && n < N - 1) {
    C[n] = (C[n] + C[n] + C[n - 1] + C[n + 1]) * 0.25f;
}

computes convoluted values from 1022 elements at most. For faster convolution, you can prepare a 1022-wide kernel of coefficients, then compute its FFT in compile time, then only in run-time compute the FFT of the array of 1024 elements and multiply the FFT of kernel and FFT of array, then compute the inverse-FFT of the result. This should give the convolution faster than brute force (i.e. scanning all elements to compute last element).
Normally this works as is for symmetric kernels (like gravitational force field kernel in 2D/3D to compute all-pair forces between planets) but this version may require some tricks before or after computations.
FFT is O(NlogN) so using 1024 (or less) cuda threads to do it should do less number of total work than brute force and in parallel so each thread (N threads assumed) would do about logN operations instead of N.
To do this inside a kernel, you can implement a Complex type, then a bit-reversing function then a 1024-element FFT function using 2-wide twiddling(called butterfly) operations in parallel. Or use Cuda's FFT API.

This is not real code. It is just an example to show why it would need to be solved stepwise in sync. Thanks though.
